# High CPU Usage because of irqbalanc1 AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a problem with one of my EC2 instance running an CI tools (Jenkins). After several build, an irqbalanc1 process appears and took 100% of CPU usage on the instance. This affect a lot the performance of my CI tools. Even by stopping the CI tools, the irqbalanc1 remains ! The only way is to restart the system but it will appear again after a while.
Do you have any idea where this process comes from ? Is there a way to avoid it ?
Thanks in advance for your help.
BR

Comment: It seems irqbalanc1 may be malware used for crytocurrency mining. You may want to check if your systems been compromised.

Comment: Possibly related: https://mobile.twitter.com/jenkinsci/status/864178120827428864

Comment: Thanks for those information. I checked on the server there is no "conn" process and after rebooting without jenkins launch, no irqbalance appears.
Moreover even by restarting jenkins but without launching any jobs, I didn't succeed to reproduce the problem. So it seems to be linked of the jenkins job content.